# Pulling value from rows, using Ajax and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, dom

I created this small script, from what I have learned about Ajax + Javascript so far.
I am running this in Chrome btw, so  `XMLHttpRequest();` should be working

PHP,

```
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=test', 'root', '')

    $stmt = $conn->query("SELECT text FROM ajax");
    foreach($stmt as $each){

?>
```

Ajax,

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', <?php echo $each['text']; ?>, false);
    request.send();
    console.log(request);

</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Now, in database `test` where tbl name is `ajax` I have rows `id` & `text`, in which `text` has three filled-in rows, but the ajax code is not showing me anything. It is not echoing anything at all, let alone update instantly, when I am adding texts in my rows. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would recommend you to use jQuery for ajax requests..

Comment: I would love to @Dremp but, I have no clue of jQuery

Comment: that code.. can get changed into $.get('<?php echo $each['text']; ?>', function(data) { /* console.log(data); */});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**out.php**

```
<?php
     $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=test', 'root', '')

     $stmt = $conn->query("SELECT text FROM ajax");
     echo json_encode($stmt);
?>
```

**test.html**

```
<script>
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', "http://mysite.com/out.php", false);
    request.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (request.readyState==4 && request.status==200)
        {
             var data = JSON.stringify(request.responseText); //The data from the server will be in responseText
             //data now contains an array of JSON objects of your data
             for(i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
                 console.log(data[i].text);   //.text is a variable based on your MYSQL field
             }
        }
    }
    request.send();
    console.log(request);
</script>
```

First you need to make a php script that outputs the data straight out nothing else (as in the out.php section above) and then have the javascript script in a whole other page (as in the test.html section) and give the `request.open` call the url to out.php in the example above `http://mysite.com/out.php`, but replace that with your actual url to the out.php file, and since you are on localhost something like   `http://localhost/Portal/Test/out.php`

Comment: I tried your code, although I undestood some of the mistakes I've made, but I did not get the script to work. Nothing is being desplayed: btw: I replaced all my ajax script with mine.

Comment: I just reedited my answer a moment ago i had `xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200` when it needed to be `request.readyState==4 && request.status==200` to match your variable name, did you copy the older version?

Comment: And is your `text` field a url or just text? if it is just text that wont work, the ajax call needs a url to where the data it is trying to retrieve is being outputted.

Comment: It is pure text, so how do I assing the url? Sorry, for the noob question. Just show me that one, and I'll stop bothering you

Comment: I am on localhost btw: `localhost/Portal/Test/ajax.php`

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect what you need to know.

Comment: What does this mean? `{"queryString":"SELECT text FROM ajax"}` I am getting that in my browser.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29680/discussion-between-patrick-evans-and-kranz-dot)

Answer (score 0):

First I would remove the *foreach* loop. Change it to the following:

```
echo json_encode($stmt);
```

That will give your AJAX *request* variable a JSON encoded object to work with. Currently your *result* variable from your AJAX request is only displaying the results within the console.

Maybe try changing *console.log(request)* to the follwing:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(request));
```

Comment: Changed it, but How do I manupilate the the object inside the ajax code?

Comment: JSON objects are the equivalent of an associative array in PHP. In other words instead of using a numerical value for the values key, a string can be used.

Research JS & JSON objects as there are tons of examples of looping through the object.